# What is the difference between using synchronizedCollection and just synchronized (collection)?

Tags: java, collections, synchronization

1.6 Javadoc is not clear on this. What is the difference between

```
List l = LinkedList();
synchronized (l) {
    l.add... // do some work
    l.set...
    l.remove...
}
```

vs.

```
List l = LinkedList();
Collection c = Collections.synchronizedCollection (l);
synchronized (c) {
    c.add...; c.set....; c.remove...
}
```

???
Why the need for a synchronizedCollection class? What is wrong with the first method?

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong with the first method?

Nothing is wrong with it: as long as you synchronize all access, your program is going to perform as expected.

> Why the need for a synchronizedCollection class?

In case you are going to use it inside a `synchronized` block, there's no reason indeed: the additional synchronization inside the collection is not going to lock other readers and writers, because `synchronized` block already does this.

The reason behind using `synchronizedCollection` in the first place is to avoid `synchronized` blocks. Calling `add`, `set`, and `remove` without synchronization will not leave your collection in an invalid state.

However, in the absence a `synchronized` block outside the statements, the three individual operations would not be executed as an atomic block.

Comment: But according to javadoc:  If multiple threads access a linked list concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. ....THIS IS TYPICALLY ACCOMPLISHED BY SYNCHRONISING ON SOME OBJECT THAT NATURALLY EXCAPSULATES THE LIST. If no such object exists, the list should be "wrapped" using the Collections.synchronizedList method. So here is what I don't understand, why does javadoc say synchronization is typically done on the encapsulating object, instead of the linked list object itself?

Comment: @FaiLau The object returned by `synchronizedCollection` is *not* a linked list. It has linked list inside it, but it's a special class that adds its own synchronization before calling the actual list.

Comment: OK, I get it now. SyncrhonizedCollection returns a thread-safe façade to the containing class. But the object returned is thread-safe, not concurrent. So when an iterator is used the object still needs to be synchronized.

Comment: @FaiLau Yes, you need to manually synchronize when you iterate or when you have to perform several operations atomically (e.g. delete an item and insert another item in a way that external observers never see your collection in the middle of the operation, when one item is already deleted, but the other one has not been inserted yet).